# SVD in a term document matrix do not give me values I want

Tags: r, matrix, text-mining, svd, lsa

I am trying to replicate an example in a paper called "An introduction to LSA": 
[An introduction to LSA](http://lsa.colorado.edu/papers/dp1.LSAintro.pdf)

In the example they have the following term-document matrix:

[image]

And then they apply SVD and get the following:

[image]

Trying to replicate this, I wrote the following R code:

```
library(lsa); library(tm)

d1 = "Human machine interface for ABC computer applications"
d2 = "A survey of user opinion of computer system response time"
d3 = "The EPS user interface management system"
d4 = "System and human system engineering testing of EPS"
d5 <- "Relation of user perceived response time to error measurement"
d6 <- "The generation of random, binary, ordered trees"
d7 <- "The intersection graph of paths in trees"
d8 <- "Graph minors IV: Widths of trees and well-quasi-ordering"
d9 <- "Graph minors: A survey"

# Words that appear in at least two of the titles
D <- c(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9)

corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(D))

# Remove Punctuation
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)

# tolower
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))

# Stopword Removal
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords("english")))

# term document Matrix
myMatrix <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)

# Delete terms that only appear in a document
rowTotals <- apply(myMatrix, 1, sum)
myMatrix.new <- myMatrix[rowTotals > 1, ]

# Correlation Matrix of terms
cor(t(as.matrix(myMatrix.new)))

# lsaSpace <- lsa(myMatrix.new)
# myMatrix.reduced <- lsaSpace$tk %*% diag(lsaSpace$sk) %*% t(lsaSpace$dk)

mySVD <- svd(myMatrix.new)
```

I got the same term-document matrix, and actually obtained the same correlations:

```
> inspect(myMatrix.new)
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 12, documents: 9)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 28/80
Sparsity           : 74%
Maximal term length: 9
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

           Docs
Terms       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  computer  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  eps       0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  graph     0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
  human     1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  interface 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  minors    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
  response  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
  survey    0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  system    0 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0
  time      0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
  trees     0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
  user      0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
> cor(as.matrix(t(myMatrix.new)))
            computer        eps      graph      human  interface     minors
computer   1.0000000 -0.2857143 -0.3779645  0.3571429  0.3571429 -0.2857143
eps       -0.2857143  1.0000000 -0.3779645  0.3571429  0.3571429 -0.2857143
graph     -0.3779645 -0.3779645  1.0000000 -0.3779645 -0.3779645  0.7559289
human      0.3571429  0.3571429 -0.3779645  1.0000000  0.3571429 -0.2857143
interface  0.3571429  0.3571429 -0.3779645  0.3571429  1.0000000 -0.2857143
minors    -0.2857143 -0.2857143  0.7559289 -0.2857143 -0.2857143  1.0000000
response   0.3571429 -0.2857143 -0.3779645 -0.2857143 -0.2857143 -0.2857143
survey     0.3571429 -0.2857143  0.1889822 -0.2857143 -0.2857143  0.3571429
system     0.0433555  0.8237545 -0.4588315  0.4335550  0.0433555 -0.3468440
time       0.3571429 -0.2857143 -0.3779645 -0.2857143 -0.2857143 -0.2857143
trees     -0.3779645 -0.3779645  0.5000000 -0.3779645 -0.3779645  0.1889822
user       0.1889822  0.1889822 -0.5000000 -0.3779645  0.1889822 -0.3779645
            response     survey     system       time      trees       user
computer   0.3571429  0.3571429  0.0433555  0.3571429 -0.3779645  0.1889822
eps       -0.2857143 -0.2857143  0.8237545 -0.2857143 -0.3779645  0.1889822
graph     -0.3779645  0.1889822 -0.4588315 -0.3779645  0.5000000 -0.5000000
human     -0.2857143 -0.2857143  0.4335550 -0.2857143 -0.3779645 -0.3779645
interface -0.2857143 -0.2857143  0.0433555 -0.2857143 -0.3779645  0.1889822
minors    -0.2857143  0.3571429 -0.3468440 -0.2857143  0.1889822 -0.3779645
response   1.0000000  0.3571429  0.0433555  1.0000000 -0.3779645  0.7559289
survey     0.3571429  1.0000000  0.0433555  0.3571429 -0.3779645  0.1889822
system     0.0433555  0.0433555  1.0000000  0.0433555 -0.4588315  0.2294157
time       1.0000000  0.3571429  0.0433555  1.0000000 -0.3779645  0.7559289
trees     -0.3779645 -0.3779645 -0.4588315 -0.3779645  1.0000000 -0.5000000
user       0.7559289  0.1889822  0.2294157  0.7559289 -0.5000000  1.0000000
```

However I tried to apply SVD to the matrix, and the only values that are equal are the eigenvalues, I cannot get what they got in the paper.

```
> mySVD
$d
[1] 3.3408838 2.5417010 2.3539435 1.6445323 1.5048316 1.3063820 0.8459031
[8] 0.5601344 0.3636768

$u
             [,1]        [,2]       [,3]          [,4]        [,5]        [,6]
 [1,] -0.24047023 -0.04315195  0.1644291  0.5949618181 -0.10675529 -0.25495513
 [2,] -0.30082816  0.14127047 -0.3303084 -0.1880919179  0.11478462  0.27215528
 [3,] -0.03613585 -0.62278523 -0.2230864 -0.0007000721 -0.06825294  0.11490895
 [4,] -0.22135078  0.11317962 -0.2889582  0.4147507404 -0.10627512 -0.34098332
 [5,] -0.19764540  0.07208778 -0.1350396  0.5522395837  0.28176894  0.49587801
 [6,] -0.03175633 -0.45050892 -0.1411152  0.0087294706 -0.30049511  0.27734340
 [7,] -0.26503747 -0.10715957  0.4259985 -0.0738121922  0.08031938 -0.16967639
 [8,] -0.20591786 -0.27364743  0.1775970  0.0323519366 -0.53715000  0.08094398
 [9,] -0.64448115  0.16730121 -0.3611482 -0.3334616013 -0.15895498 -0.20652259
[10,] -0.26503747 -0.10715957  0.4259985 -0.0738121922  0.08031938 -0.16967639
[11,] -0.01274618 -0.49016179 -0.2311202 -0.0248019985  0.59416952 -0.39212506
[12,] -0.40359886 -0.05707026  0.3378035 -0.0991137295  0.33173372  0.38483192
              [,7]          [,8]        [,9]
 [1,] -0.302240236  0.0623280150 -0.49244436
 [2,]  0.032994110 -0.0189980144  0.16533917
 [3,]  0.159575477 -0.6811254380 -0.23196123
 [4,]  0.522657771 -0.0604501376  0.40667751
 [5,] -0.070423441 -0.0099400372  0.10893027
 [6,]  0.339495286  0.6784178789 -0.18253498
 [7,]  0.282915727 -0.0161465472  0.05387469
 [8,] -0.466897525 -0.0362988295  0.57942611
 [9,] -0.165828575  0.0342720233 -0.27069629
[10,]  0.282915727 -0.0161465472  0.05387469
[11,] -0.288317461  0.2545679452  0.22542407
[12,]  0.002872175 -0.0003905042 -0.01232935

$v
              [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]          [,6]
 [1,] -0.197392802  0.05591352 -0.11026973  0.94978502  0.04567856 -7.659356e-02
 [2,] -0.605990269 -0.16559288  0.49732649  0.02864890 -0.20632728 -2.564752e-01
 [3,] -0.462917508  0.12731206 -0.20760595 -0.04160920  0.37833623  7.243996e-01
 [4,] -0.542114417  0.23175523 -0.56992145 -0.26771404 -0.20560471 -3.688609e-01
 [5,] -0.279469108 -0.10677472  0.50544991 -0.15003543  0.32719441  3.481305e-02
 [6,] -0.003815213 -0.19284794 -0.09818424 -0.01508149  0.39484121 -3.001611e-01
 [7,] -0.014631468 -0.43787488 -0.19295557 -0.01550719  0.34948535 -2.122014e-01
 [8,] -0.024136835 -0.61512190 -0.25290398 -0.01019901  0.14979847  9.743417e-05
 [9,] -0.081957368 -0.52993707 -0.07927315  0.02455491 -0.60199299  3.622190e-01
             [,7]         [,8]        [,9]
 [1,]  0.17731830 -0.014393259  0.06369229
 [2,] -0.43298424  0.049305326 -0.24278290
 [3,] -0.23688970  0.008825502 -0.02407687
 [4,]  0.26479952 -0.019466944  0.08420690
 [5,]  0.67230353 -0.058349563  0.26237588
 [6,] -0.34083983  0.454476523  0.61984719
 [7,] -0.15219472 -0.761527011 -0.01797518
 [8,]  0.24914592  0.449642757 -0.51989050
 [9,]  0.03803419 -0.069637550  0.45350675
```

Am I missing something?

Best Regards

EDIT:

It is supposed in the example, that the dimension is reduced and they deleted the less eigenvalues. My problem is that the correlations I get after SVD are different than that of the example:

[image]

Comment: Note that your matrix is also in a different order. You can compare: `mm<-as.matrix(myMatrix.new); lapply(svd(mm[match(c("human","interface","computer","user","system","response","time","eps","survey","trees","graph","minors"), rownames(mm)), ]),round,2)` seems like there's still some different in v/p but w/u matches.

Comment: You are right, the terms are not in the same order. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find my mistake. When I was reconstructing the matrix, the transpose of the M = U D V' was not computed correctly. Now it works, sorry, it was my mistake... Also, I was computing cor between documents, when what I wanted was between terms.

I added the following lines:

```
mySVD <- svd(myMatrix.new)

Mp <- mySVD$u[, c(1,2)] %*% diag(mySVD$d)[c(1, 2), c(1, 2)] %*% t(mySVD$v[, c(1, 2)])

rownames(Mp) <- rownames(myMatrix.new)
cor(t(Mp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for protocol, setting up on your matrix `myMatrix` I was able to near exactly reconstruct the example. The only difference (possible explainable?) is in some opposite signs in the Figure 2 (e.g. `u[1,1]` is `-0.22` instead of `0.22` as in the `W[1,1]` Figure 2).
The correlation Matrix is identical.

It should be mentioned though, that contrary to the claim in the paper (p. 13) that the Spearman correlation is used, the exact result is obtained using the (default) Pearson correlation method.

Here the code:

```
> # term document Matrix
> myMatrix <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
> 
> ## reorder rows
> myMatrix <- mm[match(c("human","interface","computer","user","system","response","time","eps","survey","trees","graph","minors"), rownames(mm)), ]
> 
> # Delete terms that only appear in a document
> rowTotals <- apply(myMatrix, 1, sum)
> myMatrix.new <- myMatrix[rowTotals > 1, ]
> 
> mySVD <- svd(myMatrix.new)
> 
> ## Figure 1
> myMatrix.new 
           Docs
Terms       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  human     1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  interface 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  computer  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  user      0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
  system    0 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0
  response  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
  time      0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
  eps       0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  survey    0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
  trees     0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
  graph     0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
  minors    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
> 
> ## mySVD Figure 2
> lapply(mySVD,round,2)
$d
[1] 3.34 2.54 2.35 1.64 1.50 1.31 0.85 0.56 0.36

$u
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
 [1,] -0.22 -0.11  0.29 -0.41 -0.11 -0.34 -0.52  0.06  0.41
 [2,] -0.20 -0.07  0.14 -0.55  0.28  0.50  0.07  0.01  0.11
 [3,] -0.24  0.04 -0.16 -0.59 -0.11 -0.25  0.30 -0.06 -0.49
 [4,] -0.40  0.06 -0.34  0.10  0.33  0.38  0.00  0.00 -0.01
 [5,] -0.64 -0.17  0.36  0.33 -0.16 -0.21  0.17 -0.03 -0.27
 [6,] -0.27  0.11 -0.43  0.07  0.08 -0.17 -0.28  0.02  0.05
 [7,] -0.27  0.11 -0.43  0.07  0.08 -0.17 -0.28  0.02  0.05
 [8,] -0.30 -0.14  0.33  0.19  0.11  0.27 -0.03  0.02  0.17
 [9,] -0.21  0.27 -0.18 -0.03 -0.54  0.08  0.47  0.04  0.58
[10,] -0.01  0.49  0.23  0.02  0.59 -0.39  0.29 -0.25  0.23
[11,] -0.04  0.62  0.22  0.00 -0.07  0.11 -0.16  0.68 -0.23
[12,] -0.03  0.45  0.14 -0.01 -0.30  0.28 -0.34 -0.68 -0.18

$v
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
 [1,] -0.20 -0.06  0.11 -0.95  0.05 -0.08 -0.18  0.01  0.06
 [2,] -0.61  0.17 -0.50 -0.03 -0.21 -0.26  0.43 -0.05 -0.24
 [3,] -0.46 -0.13  0.21  0.04  0.38  0.72  0.24 -0.01 -0.02
 [4,] -0.54 -0.23  0.57  0.27 -0.21 -0.37 -0.26  0.02  0.08
 [5,] -0.28  0.11 -0.51  0.15  0.33  0.03 -0.67  0.06  0.26
 [6,]  0.00  0.19  0.10  0.02  0.39 -0.30  0.34 -0.45  0.62
 [7,] -0.01  0.44  0.19  0.02  0.35 -0.21  0.15  0.76 -0.02
 [8,] -0.02  0.62  0.25  0.01  0.15  0.00 -0.25 -0.45 -0.52
 [9,] -0.08  0.53  0.08 -0.02 -0.60  0.36 -0.04  0.07  0.45

> 
> Mp <- mySVD$u[, c(1,2)] %*% diag(mySVD$d)[c(1, 2), c(1, 2)] %*% t(mySVD$v[, c(1, 2)])
> rownames(Mp) <- rownames(myMatrix.new)
> 
> ## Figure 3
> round(Mp,2)
           [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
human      0.16 0.40  0.38  0.47 0.18 -0.05 -0.12 -0.16 -0.09
interface  0.14 0.37  0.33  0.40 0.16 -0.03 -0.07 -0.10 -0.04
computer   0.15 0.51  0.36  0.41 0.24  0.02  0.06  0.09  0.12
user       0.26 0.84  0.61  0.70 0.39  0.03  0.08  0.12  0.19
system     0.45 1.23  1.05  1.27 0.56 -0.07 -0.15 -0.21 -0.05
response   0.16 0.58  0.38  0.42 0.28  0.06  0.13  0.19  0.22
time       0.16 0.58  0.38  0.42 0.28  0.06  0.13  0.19  0.22
eps        0.22 0.55  0.51  0.63 0.24 -0.07 -0.14 -0.20 -0.11
survey     0.10 0.53  0.23  0.21 0.27  0.14  0.31  0.44  0.42
trees     -0.06 0.23 -0.14 -0.27 0.14  0.24  0.55  0.77  0.66
graph     -0.06 0.34 -0.15 -0.30 0.20  0.31  0.69  0.98  0.85
minors    -0.04 0.25 -0.10 -0.21 0.15  0.22  0.50  0.71  0.62
> 
> cor(Mp["human",],Mp["minors",])
[1] -0.83
> 
> cor(Mp["human",],Mp["user",])
[1] 0.94
> 
> ## Figure 4
> corMo <- cor(myMatrix.new)
> corMo[upper.tri(corMo,diag=TRUE)] <- 0
> corMo
      1     2     3     4     5     6    7    8 9
1  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00 0.00 0
2 -0.19  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00 0.00 0
3  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00 0.00 0
4  0.00  0.00  0.47  0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00 0.00 0
5 -0.33  0.58  0.00 -0.31  0.00  0.00 0.00 0.00 0
6 -0.17 -0.30 -0.21 -0.16 -0.17  0.00 0.00 0.00 0
7 -0.26 -0.45 -0.32 -0.24 -0.26  0.67 0.00 0.00 0
8 -0.33 -0.58 -0.41 -0.31 -0.33  0.52 0.77 0.00 0
9 -0.33 -0.19 -0.41 -0.31 -0.33 -0.17 0.26 0.56 0
> 
> corMp <- cor(Mp)
> corMp[upper.tri(corMp,diag=TRUE)] <- 0
> corMp
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00    0    0    0    0
 [2,]  0.91  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00    0    0    0    0
 [3,]  1.00  0.91  0.00  0.00  0.00    0    0    0    0
 [4,]  1.00  0.88  1.00  0.00  0.00    0    0    0    0
 [5,]  0.84  0.99  0.84  0.81  0.00    0    0    0    0
 [6,] -0.86 -0.57 -0.86 -0.89 -0.44    0    0    0    0
 [7,] -0.85 -0.56 -0.85 -0.88 -0.44    1    0    0    0
 [8,] -0.85 -0.56 -0.85 -0.88 -0.43    1    1    0    0
 [9,] -0.81 -0.50 -0.81 -0.84 -0.37    1    1    1    0
>
```